# Get C# value in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am new to C# and want to get my C# value in javascript

I found that by doing `var javacriptVariable = "<%=CsVariable%>";` it should get the value CsVariable aut of my .cs file. However when I log it it logs `<%=CsVariable%>` as a string

How can I get the value out m C# file?

Comment: Sounds like you are not getting the value from C# and are just assigning that as a string. How are you logging and where is your javascript e.g. inline, in its own file etc.?

Comment: @majita that exactly whats happening. the part i use for testing this is `var javacriptVariable = "<%=this.CsVariable%>"; console.log(javacriptVariable)  `

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Web Forms?

Comment: @ErikT. no i am not using that

Comment: As far as I know that is just the syntax if you are using ASP.NET Web Forms. What kind of project do you have? Is it ASP.NET at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Approach I usually take is to assign the C# value to a hidden input field in which you can obtain the value data from javascript. In ASP.NET (Which it appears you are using, correct me if I am wrong) you can do something like

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" id="hdnCsVariable" />
```

And then in the backend .cs file on page load

```
hdnCsVariable.Value = "My C# Value";
```

And finally in the JS since ASP.NET will (usually) generate some hideous id, you can use the "ends with" selector to get your hidden input like so

```
console.log(document.querySelector("input[id$='hdnCsVariable']").value); // logs "My C# Value"
```

Comment: As for your last point, it's much more reliable to use the ClientID property from the control rather than hardcoding it like you've done.. `<%= hdnCsVariable.ClientID %>`

Comment: @Adriani6 is it possible to get this client id in a javascript file that does not have access to the aspx page?

Comment: Yes, attach the ID as a global variable and retrieve it in other JS files. There's many ways however OP does not mention a separate JS file.

Answer (score 0):

While Dans solution will work, here's an alternative that I'd personally go for..

[`RegisterStartupScript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript?view=netframework-4.8)

Example usage:

`this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", string.Format("var myVariable = {0};", 123), true);`

The following will render whatever you put inside the 3rd argument as a script on the page, therefore I'd put it in a PostBack or perhaps inside onPageLoad.

Answer (score 0):

1. In Asp.net you can easily use
2. **Use Variable**
3. protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox MyTextBox;
4. '<%= MyTextBox.ClientID %>'
5. **Use Function**
6. '<%=UI.ClassName.GetFunctionName%>'